# How to provide an arbitrary value of a non-empty type (parameter) in a subset type witness clause?

Tags: dafny

I am trying to introduce a parameterized subset type (`Bar<T(0)>` below) requiring me to provide a witness of type `T`:

```
datatype Foo<T> = Foo(x: T)
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true witness ???
```

Since `T` is non-empty, I don't see a reason why this should not be possible.

My attempts:

```
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true witness Foo(*) // Error: closeparen expected
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true witness Foo(var x: T := *; x) // Error: invalid UnaryExpression
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true witness Foo(var x: T :| true; x) // Error: to be compilable, the value of a let-such-that expression must be uniquely determined
```

I speculated that I may be able to write a function, function method or method to help out, but failed here as well. A method can be used to obtain an arbitrary `T`:

```
method Pick<T(0)>() returns (x: T)
{
}
```

But a `witness` clause would require a function method while a `ghost witness` would require a function. When trying to obtain an arbitrary `T` in either of those, I get the same errors as the ones I pointed out above. Calling `Pick` in methods or function methods isn't possible either.

I understand that I can specify `witness *`, but this seems more of a hack than a proper solution. Or should I not be bothered by it?

Comment: Third attempt works with ghost witness (if you only care about verification but not code extraction).

Comment: @DivyanshuRanjan: Ooooh ... now I feel stupid.  Seems like I only tried this one in my "witness" and "function method" attempts :/

From the reference: "If the witness is only available in ghost code, you can declare the witness as a ghost witness. In this case, the Dafny verifier knows that the type is non-empty, but it will not be able to auto-initialize a variable of that type in compiled code."

Indeed I don't need auto-initialization in compiled code in my case, so this works fine for me.

Comment: I see that I should have realized that  `var x: T :| true; x` should have worked, because I'm using `:|` all the time in functions. Any idea why `var x: T := *; x` or more specifically `*` is not allowed in functions while `var x: T :| true; x` is? Don't they essentially have the same semantics? https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-rhs-expression makes it sound like `*` would be "worse" in functions than the `:|` solution.

Comment: No idea about this. Strangely It is parser error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DivyanshuRanjan answered the question in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188695/how-to-provide-an-arbitrary-value-of-a-non-empty-type-parameter-in-a-subset-ty?noredirect=1#comment134359568_76188695), which I will try to summarize here.

The following works:

```
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true ghost witness Foo(var x: T :| true; x)
```

It works because `ghost` witnesses don't need to be compilable and `var x: T :| true; x` is an expression that is valid in functions, i.e. non-compiled contexts. In a non-`ghost` witness clause the verifier would reject this expression with the error shown above ("Error: to be compilable, the value of a let-such-that expression must be uniquely determined").

According to the [reference manual](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-witness), the drawback of a `ghost witness` is that "[the Dafny verifier] will not be able to auto-initialize a variable of that type in compiled code."

The following is not valid:

```
type Bar<T(0)> = x: Foo<T> | true ghost witness Foo(var x: T := *; x)
```

According to the [reference manual](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-rhs-expression) `*` is a "Right-Hand-Side Expression":

> A Right-Hand-Side expression is an expression-like construct that may have side-effects. Consequently such expressions can only be used within certain statements within methods, and not as general expressions or within functions or specifications.
> An RHS is either an array allocation, an object allocation, a havoc right-hand-side, a method call, or a simple expression, optionally followed by one or more attributes.

I fail to see how `var x: T := *; x` differs from `var x: T :| true; x` (other than the fact that one is usable in functions and the other isn't.) I hope that this part of the answer can be improved in the future.